# hardcoding wallet address into smart contract

Tags: solidity, remix, nft

How can I hardcode a wallet address into my smart contract to ensure that the funds are only withdrawn to that address and cannot be changed to a different address ?

Answer (score 1):

There's lots of was to do this, this takes the specified tokens from the smart contract and sends them directly to the specified wallet.

```
address immutable myAddress = 0x000000000000000000000000000000000000dEaD; // put your address here
function sendTokensFromContract(address _token, uint256 _amount) public { 
    IERC20(_token).transfer(myAddress, _amount); // can be any transferable token including your own
    }
```

Comment: Will this mean the wallet has been hardcoded?

Comment: Correct. You could view "hardcoded" in two ways, something that can't be change or nobody has access to change it. In the above code, *myAddress* can never be changed after it's declared. 

Additionally, solidity makes the score private by default. Set variables to public or external for other contracts to read them, and internal for only inside your deployment.

Comment: @FudgyDRS `immutable` is commonly used when the variable is initialized once in the constructor. If the address is know beforehand you'll use `address constant` instead.

Comment: Thank you so much for your input on this Ismael, To clarify by using address constant would it mean that no method can be added to the contract by the developer to change the withdrawal address after deployment?